# Angular 5 add amphtml link tag dynamically on server-side rendering

Tags: angular, angular5, amp-html, angular-universal

I have Angular 5 SPA with server-side rendering. I want to add links to google amp static pages dynamically to `<head>` e.g.:

`<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/amp/dynamic.amp.html">`

I found angular already have similar functionality implemented in [@angular/platform-browser/Meta](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta) and 
[@angular/platform-browser/Title](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title). How do I implement similar approach but for the link tags? I want amp links to be prerendered and accessible by robots in viewsource without running js.

Comment: Perhaps not the best solution but one that should work, you can simple add it by adding it to the "html text" renderer by the universal motor. I'm personnaly using node  so juste before doing : res.send(html);  you can add your link tag before the </head> tag

Comment: @xrobert35 thanks man, I posted the solution I ended up with, you can post yours also, as my relates to angular `main.server.ts`, not to node

Comment: The general idea is here  :) I think poeple can easily understand

Answer (score 0):

okay so thanks to @xrobert35 I ended up with this solution which seems to be working fine with ssr and my ASP.NET Core + Angular 5 project

in `main.server.ts` I edited `createServerRenderer()` to intercept `html` returned as string and added `<link>` tag as text right after the `<head>`

obviously `NO AMP LINK DEFINED FOR CURRENT PAGE` is for debug purposes and you should avoid adding the whole tag in case if no amp pages available

```
let promise = renderPromise.then(html => {
        let ampTag = `<link rel="amphtml" href="${ampHTMLPages[params.url] || 'NO AMP LINK DEFINED FOR CURRENT PAGE'}">`;
        return { html: html.replace("<head>", `<head>${ampTag}`) };
    });
```

For those who need adding my full `main.server.ts` below:

```js
import { RoutePaths } from './app/shared/routePaths.constants';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import { createServerRenderer } from 'aspnet-prerendering';
export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
import { ORIGIN_URL } from './app/shared/baseurl.constants';

enableProdMode();

export default createServerRenderer(params => {
    const { AppServerModule, AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = (module as any).exports;

    const options = {
        document: params.data.originalHtml,
        url: params.url,
        extraProviders: [
            provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
            { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
            { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: params.origin + params.baseUrl },
            { provide: ORIGIN_URL, useValue: params.origin }
        ]
    };

    const ampHTMLPages = {
        [RoutePaths.exampleRoute]: 'some/amp/page/example.html'
    }

    const renderPromise = AppServerModuleNgFactory
        ? /* AoT */ renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, options)
        : /* dev */ renderModule(AppServerModule, options);

    let promise = renderPromise.then(html => {
        //@see https://www.ampproject.org/docs/getting_started/create/prepare_for_discovery
        let ampTag = `<link rel="amphtml" href="${ampHTMLPages[params.url] || 'NO AMP LINK DEFINED FOR CURRENT PAGE'}">`;
        return { html: html.replace("<head>", `<head>${ampTag}`) };
    });
    promise.catch(response => { console.error(response) });
    return promise;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Here, how I solve my problem thanks to this post : http://blog.davidjs.com/2018/09/insert-script-tags-in-angular-components/

To add/change the title or meta balise, I use `import { Title, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser'`:

```
import { Title, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';


constructor(
    private titleService:Title,
    private metaService:Meta
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    // Set the page title
    this.titleService.setTitle('title');

    // Update the meta balise 'name=description'
    if (this.metaService.getTag('name=description')) {
        this.metaService.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: 'New Meta' }, `name='description'`);
        } else {
        this.metaService.addTag({ name:'description', content: 'New Meta' });
    }
}
```

To add a new balise like a link or a script, I use `import { Inject, Renderer2  } from '@angular/core';` and `import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';`:

```
import { Inject, Renderer2  } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';


constructor(
    private renderer2: Renderer2,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    const link = this.renderer2.createElement('link');
    link.rel = "amphtml";
    link.href = "https://www.example.com/amp/dynamic.amp.html";
    this.renderer2.appendChild(this._document.head, link);
}
```

I hope my answer can help.